# Android - Calling a DialogFragment method from a Class to close the soft keyboard of DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard

Good day. Sorry for the long title, I had to be descriptive.

I have an Android Application where I have a Custom ListView with an EditText and a DialogFragment on top of it. The user can still see the EditText as the DialogFragment does not cover the whole screen and the user can still select the EditText in the ListView. The EditText in my Custom ListView has a [custom Keyboard from this tutorial](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm). My Dialog Fragment contains an Edit Text that uses the default Android Soft Keyboard.

The main issue/problem I have is that when the user clicks the EditText in my Dialog Fragment (the android soft keyboard shows up) and clicks on the EditText in the Custom ListView, my Custom Keyboard shows up behind the Android Soft Keyboard and the Android Soft Keyboard does not collapse/hide.

One work around I did was this:

I made the root view of the Dialog Fragment (the parent view of the EditText) be selectable as such:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

So that the focus isn't "locked" or monopolized by the EditText. I also created a function in the DialogFragment class that hides the soft keyboard. I have two of them and they both work:

```
public void hideKB(){

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(instructionInput.getWindowToken(), 0);
    //instructionInput is my EditText

}

public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

And I call either of them as such:

```
instructionInput.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            hideKB();
            //hideKeyboard(v);
        }
    }
});
```

And it works fine. When the user clicks on the Dialog Fragment the soft keyboard closes.

Now, I want to call this function or achieve the same effect when the user clicks on the EditText in my Custom ListView. The Custom Keyboard class in my EditText has this function:

```
public void registerEditText(int resid, final SearchResult context, final ItemDialog itemDialog) {
    EditText edittext= (EditText)mHostActivity.findViewById(resid);
    edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if( hasFocus ) {
                Log.d("hello","edittext focused");

                itemDialog.hideKB(); 
                showCustomKeyboard(v); 

            }
            else {  
                hideCustomKeyboard();
            }
        }
    });

    //removed extra lines of code

}
```

Kindly not that `SearchResult` is the Base Activity of the DialogFragment and that `ItemDialog` is my Dialog Fragment.

What I do is that when the user focuses on the EditText in the ListView, the `onFocusChange` function triggers and I try to call the `hideKB()` function of my Dialog Fragment. However, I am thrown a nullPointerException:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.agict.marswin, PID: 14038
java.lang.NullPointerException
     at UtilityClasses.CustomKeyboard$2.onFocusChange(CustomKeyboard.java:187)
```

and Line 187 at my `CustomKeyboard` is the code that calls the function from the Dialog Fragment:

```
itemDialog.hideKB();
```

And I don't get why I am getting a null pointer at that line because I called the `registerEditText` after I initialized my `itemDialog`. I think my issue boils down to calling a function of a DialogFragment from a class.

Can anyone help me? I've been working on this for the past 6+ hours and I'm stuck. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay sorry, I got it to work. The problem was the `itemDialog` was null. What I did instead was this:

In my `SearchResult` activity, I created a public ItemDialog as such:

```
public ItemDialog itemDialog;
```

Then I instantiated it normally, created, and showed it. So now I have a properly instantiated DialogFragment that can be accessed by any class since it's public.

Going to the `registerEditText()` function, here's what I did:

```
public void registerEditText(int resid, final SearchResult searchResult, final ItemDialog itemDialog) {
   @Override 
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if( hasFocus ) {
            Log.d("hello","edittext focused");

            searchResult.itemDialog.hideKB();
            showCustomKeyboard(v); 

        }
        else {  
           hideCustomKeyboard();
       }
    }
    //extra code here
}
```

Since I am passing the activity to the registerEditText function as such in my SearchResult Activity:

```
mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.qtyInputSearchResult, SearchResult.this, itemDialog); 
mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.discInputSearchResult, SearchResult.this, itemDialog);
```

(actually the last argument is no longer needed)

I can use the 2nd argument `SearchResult` to access the `itemDialog` variable (which is not null and perfectly instantiated) and from there, I can properly call my function.

I know this isn't the best way to go about it, but so far, it works.